# The loop is not getting executed as required

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

i have written the below code

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
def run_code():
    codeexecuted = False
    while True:
        minutetorun = [18,19]
        thisminute = int(datetime.now().strftime('%M'))
        if (thisminute in minutetorun) and codeexecuted == False:
            codeexecuted = True              
            print("Windows service running.")                           
        elif (thisminute not in minutetorun) and codeexecuted == True:
            codeexecuted = False
        time.sleep(30)
        
run_code()
```

I want "Windows service running." to be printed every time thecurrent minute is the one mentioned in the list (minutetorun). But it is not looping as required. What is wrong in the loop?

Comment: This code appears to work. Perhaps there's some problem with the way you are testing it.

Comment: is the code giving output everytime the minute is matching?

Comment: It won't give output for minute 19, because `codeexecuted` is still true from minute 18.

Comment: My test is also valid.

Comment: For consecutive minutes, or the second time during the same minute, you will miss out because the first time the print is executed you set `codeexecuted = True`, so all subsequent iterations will not trigger.

Comment: oh is that the reason

Comment: so this is a problem.. how can I do change if I want to run in consecutive minute?

Comment: Oh, and `datetime.now().minute` will give the minute more directly ;-)

Comment: Maintain a variable `last_minute_run` and compare it to the current minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt it like:

```
def run_code():
    last_run = None
    minutetorun = [18,19]
    while True:
        thisminute = datetime.now().minute
        if (thisminute in minutetorun) and thisminute != last_run:
            print("Windows service running.")  
            last_run = thisminute
        time.sleep(30)
```